# Using max function to use a calculated value in an svg

Tags: svg, cumulocity, scada

I have a svg and would like to use the max of two measurement values. So something like:`{{max(left, right)}}`.

This does not work and gives an error in the browser console.
How can I change the expression?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Math is not part of the angular scope here so you cannot use the max function (at least I also did not succeed).

However there is another method you can use.

```
{{firstValue > secondValue ? firstValue : secondValue}}
```

The **important** part when you use any kind of angular expression is that you need to "declare" the variables somewhere before in the SVG. Otherwise it tries to parse the whole expression as a variable name (which probably leads to the error you are getting).

You can simply add a comment somewhere in the beginning of the SVG.

```
<!-- {{firstValue}} -->
<!-- {{secondValue}} -->
```

Afterwards these variable names are known in the angular scope and the expression works.